# How to store an array of height values and use them in another script

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jquery-animate, each

I have a lot to learn so could really use some pointers: http://jsfiddle.net/David_Knowles/9kDC3/

**QUESTION**

1. I am trying store iteratively the height values of bars in a bar
   chart.
2. Then i set the height of all to zero
3. I then trigger an animation of the bars where I increase height towards the original values stored in array

**Problem**

1. It looks to me that the array is being overwritten instead of
   increasingly filled
2. I don't know what the best way is to share the array values with the
   other script I later trigger

//

```
$(function(){
// get the height of all the bars
var $theBars = $("#v-bars").children();
var BarsHeight = $theBars.each(function(index, element ) {
    var origHeight = [];
    origHeight.push($(this).attr("height"));
    console.log (origHeight);
});

//
$("#svg-skills-expertise").click(function() {
    $($theBars).each(function(){
        $(this).css("MyH",$(this).attr("height")).animate(
        {
            MyH:400 // this value needs to be the array values so how 
        },
        {
            step:function(v1){
                $(this).attr("height",v1)
            }
        })
    })
    console.log ("Yeap the clicked it! callback");
});
});
```

Comment: the `origHeight` array is being created, having 1 value pushed to it, then created all over again with each loop..

Comment: Declare the array outside the function, right now when you declare it, the scope is limited to within that function.

Answer (score 2):

[Updated!](http://jsfiddle.net/9kDC3/4/)

Initialized **origHeight** outside of your function call, added parameter "i" to **$($theBars).each** function (passes the index to the each call), and set **MyH: origHeight[i]**.

```
/* SVG ARRAY \\\\\\\\\ */

var origHeight = [];
$(function(){
    var $theBars = $("#v-bars").children();
    var BarsHeight = $theBars.each(function(index, element ) {
        origHeight.push($(this).attr("height"));
        console.log (origHeight);
    });


    $("#svg-skills-expertise").click(function() {
        $($theBars).each(function(i){
            $(this).css("MyH",$(this).attr("height")).animate(
            {
                MyH:origHeight[i]
            },
            {
                step:function(v1){
                    $(this).attr("height",v1)
                }
            })
        })
        console.log ("Yeap clicked it!");
    });
});
```